# Problems with unicode variables in subprocess.check_output Python with Django

Tags: java, python, django, unicode, utf-8

recently in my work we brought a server and cofigure it. Its just to contextualize. Now the problem is i working in a code in Java (Cogroo, a grammar checker in portuguese) and we have some codes in Python, to make work both codes together I'm calling the jar file within the Python code. When i working in my local machine it all works fine and when i put in the server a have some troubles.

```
>>> a = u"ele anda à cavalo"
>>> print(type(a))
>>> <type 'unicode'>
>>> a
u'ele anda \xe0 cavalo'
>>> print(a)
ele anda à cavalo
```

In my local machine and on the server terminal it works fine, but if i do the same on the Python Script it brings me an error like "ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' print python". In the script i can't even print a unicode string. Than when i try to call the `output = subprocess.check_output(cd.encode("utf-8"), shell=True)` var cd has the java code and path `cd = 'java -jar path/file.jar GrammarChecker -country br -lang pt -text "' + auxTextPure + '"'` the var `auxTextPure` always be a unicode string.

Look thats two problems, the first one is when the var `auxTextPure` is a istring without special caracters like **A menino** it returns a output like that **Os determinantes concordam em n?mero (singular ou plural) e em g?nero (masculino ou feminino) com o substantivo a que se referem.** and i need the output with accentuation, and the second error was when using a string with accentuation like that **Ele anda à cavalo** it brings this output **Verifique a repeti??o de palavras.** but the correct output is **O sinal indicativo de crase indica que temos "a" + "a" expressos em um só "à". Somente ocorre crase quando há encontro de preposição "a" com artigo ou pronome demonstrativo "a"/"as". Portanto, não ocorre crase antes de palavras masculinas.** with the accentuation, i know that the problem is because the Python or django on server and specific on the script can't translate unicode (UTF-8) and print on the screen or even on a variable. i try to make `cd.encode("utf-8")` `auxTextPure.encode("utf-8")` `auxTextPure.decode("utf-8")` and some other codes like `import codecs` and use this codecs and i try to find on the internet this problem, but in any place i can find how to fix this, anyone can help me please? Thanks so much, sorry for my bad english. 
Leandro Costa Valadão.

Comment: where are you running the script when you get the ascii error and as what user? I bet your locale is not set to utf-8

Comment: I change my locale to pt-br utf-8 like my local machine.

Answer (score -2):

A string should be first decoded into UTF-8 then encoded or vice versa. You never know if the string encoded or decoded originally.

1.

```
a = u"ele anda à cavalo"
print a.encode('UTF-8')
```

.

```
ele anda à cavalo
```

---

2.

```
a = u"ele anda à cavalo"
print a.decode('UTF-8')
```

.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

3.

```
a = u"ele anda à cavalo"
print a.encode('UTF-8').decode('UTF-8')
```

.

```
ele anda à cavalo
```

---

4.

```
a = u"ele anda à cavalo"
print a.encode('UTF-8').decode('UTF-8').encode('UTF-8')
```

.

```
ele anda à cavalo
```

---

Funny, isn't it?

Comment: It's nice but, i try this way and just get a string like that 'ele anda \xc3\xa0 cavalo' and i realy need a string with accenctuation. I think is a problem in servidor prompt.